# How to attach the Sonar JUnitListener when not using maven?

Tags: sonarqube

I have a Sonar analysis configured to use sonar-ant-task. 
JUnit tests are executed with the Eclipse test framework (as a JUnit Plug-in test, using the PDE) and it uses the JaCoCo agent for the on-the-fly instrumentation.
The results are then stored in the directory ./junit/results/ in JUnit XML format.

Here is the configuration for the Sonar (using Ant):

```html
<property name="sonar.projectKey" value="my-project" />
<property name="sonar.projectName" value="My Project" />
<property name="sonar.working.directory" value="./.sonar" />
<property name="sonar.sources" value="$./src" />
<property name="sonar.java.binaries" value="./bin" />
<property name="sonar.java.libraries" value="./lib" />

<property name="sonar.tests" value="./tests" />
<property name="sonar.dynamic" value="reuseReports" />
<property name="sonar.junit.reportsPath" value="./junit/result" />

<property name="sonar.java.coveragePlugin" value="jacoco" />
<property name="sonar.jacoco.reportPath" value="./jacoco/jacoco.exec" />
```

In the directory junit/result there is a file with name AllTests.xml that has this content (sensitive part in the properties section was ommitted):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite errors="0" failures="0" hostname="vmtnetci002" id="0" name="AllTests" package="com.example.company.project.tests" tests="2" time="100.000" timestamp="2015-07-09T17:31:51">
      <properties>
        <!-- ... -->
      </properties>

      <testcase classname="com.example.company.project.tests.MyTest" name="test1" time="50.000" />

      <testcase classname="com.example.company.project.tests.MyTest" name="test2" time="50.000" />

      <system-out><![CDATA[]]></system-out>

      <system-err><![CDATA[]]></system-err>

  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Code coverage is reported correctly to Sonar but during the Sonar analysis it shows this message in the log:

```
...
INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor
INFO  - parsing ./junit/results
INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor (done) | time=23ms
...
INFO  - No information about coverage per test.
```

And then I don't have information about JUnit tests result in Sonar, so I think it might be related with the message above.

How can I attach the sonar JUnitListener when running the tests?

Comment: Coverage, Coverage per test and unit test results are 3 different things. JunitListener is dedicated for coverage per test. Unit Tests results are imported via surefire report. So what exactly do you want to achieve ? display unit test results or get coverage per tests ? what is your project configuration  ?

Comment: Well, actually I want all those metrics. Coverage is working fine but coverage per test and unit test are not working. I assumed that these 2 could be related. What I want primarily is to report the unit tests. but now I realize that the message is related with coverage per test. so the question should be instead: "JUnit Plug-in tests results are not reported to Sonar". I will update the question with configurations I used.

Comment: The JunitListener relates to coverage per test. can you output what is in junir/result directory ?

Comment: @benzonico, I just added the content of the xml in junit/result directory

Comment: Can you double check the configuration is correct ? I see that you have result and results directory mentioned in your question.

Comment: the configuration is correct, it was a typo on the text. actually, if the path was wrong surefire plugin would complain that it didn't find the path, so that part is ok.

Comment: Does the test files refered by the test classes in the surefire reports are in the correct test directory and can be found by sonarqube ?

Comment: yes, as I said before, they are found by sonarqube, otherwise the log would show something saying it didn't found (it was a typo on the text here in the question, not in th configuration). BTW, the tests dir is the one containing the source test files, right?